# fix label width to use properly the outlined input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm just trying to use a  with a long label but when it gets too long it jumps the line despite having space for the word.

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bhabha-i736y

so basically, looks like it is not being properly calculated, so I want to calculate it manually, I was trying to use the label ref, but it doesnt work.

edit:

to be more precise, lets suppose our label is `I want to do this right`, right?
it will look like this:

```
---I want to do         -----
|   this right              |
-----------------------------
```

note the space that is left, that is not correct.

when it should be:

```
-- I want to do this right ------
|                               |
---------------------------------
```

as far as I saw the label has space but for some reasons, it breaks the line.
notice that this is a problem with `outlined` TextFields

Comment: What are you trying to do? is that link to the codesandbox correct?

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes it is a code sandbox, it has the cases where it is broken. also I added more explanation to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem is

`transform: translate(14px, -6px) scale(0.75);`

`transform` works **after** element was calculated and placed to the DOM.
If you will remove `scale(0.75)` you will see that your element takes all available space.

### How to fix:

remove your `transform: translate(14px, -6px) scale(0.75);` and add this code instead

```
.MuiInputLabel-outlined.MuiInputLabel-shrink {
    transform: translate(0, -6px);
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 14px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: good, it does the job of inline everything, but now some of the border line is overlapping the string, is there an easy way to solve that? I'll start looking for it, but yours is the right answer.

Comment: Looks like html structure is wrong too. When all done right everything should work correctly. Check [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset). But if you want fix it quickly you can just add  `background-color: white;`.
I have modified my answer respectively.

Comment: But I would prefer to build my own `TextField` component it is not a rocket science  :) just `<fieldset>  <legend>Mylabel:</legend>  <textarea></textarea> </fieldset>` and a few styles